# xlPasteValues not reflecting copied contents

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy the values on a certain range to another range but the `xlPastValues` function is not reflecting the contents I'm copying. There's no error, it's just showing blank cells on `F6` my range. Please help.

```
    With Worksheets(4)
    '[D4] Main date
    Worksheets(4).[J1].Value = Worksheets(1).[D4]
    '[J6:J31] holds formulas to calculate certain dates
    Worksheets(4).[J6:J31].Copy
    Worksheets(4).[F6].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
```

Comment: Can't replicate with test data. What's in `J6:J31`?

Comment: It's a list of formulas to calculate dates and I need to transfer the values to `[F6:F31]`

Comment: I've updated the code to reflect the exact code I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

may be your formulas return some "zero" dates and that the format of "F6:F31" cells is "#" so that you don't' *see* anything

otherwise try the following alternative for pasting values only:

```
With Worksheets(4)
    '[D4] Main date
    .[J1].value = Worksheets(1).[D4]
    '[J6:J31] holds formulas to calculate certain dates
    With .[J6:J31] '<--| reference "source" range
        .Offset(, -4).value = .value '<--| "destination" range is 4 columns left of the "source" one
    End With
End With
```